# How can I construct perfect Conditions

Tags: c#, if-statement

Here is my problem: I want to create a program to check for errors in ATM and compare it with the saved data in my Database to get an SMS with the error status of each machine ( Solved , Unsolved , New ). The program is done and it works just fine, but crashed and after restore the conditions in the `CompareErrs`-method stopped working. As it suppose to now it returns the solved ERRORS SAME AS THE NEW. Here is the Function :-
please Help with the conditions :S

```
   private object[] CompareErrs(string MachineErr, string DBErr)        
    {
        #region CompareErrs
        object[] ToReturn = new object[2];

        string Errs_Solved = "";
        string Errs_UnSolved = "";
        string Errs_New = "";

        string[] MachineErrSplit = MachineErr.Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < MachineErrSplit.Length; i++)
        {
            string Seperator = " ";
            //if (i == MachineErrSplit.Length - 1)
            //    Seperator = "";

            if (DBErr.Contains(MachineErrSplit[i]))
            {
                Errs_UnSolved += MachineErrSplit[i] + Seperator;
            }
            else //if (MachineErrSplit[i].Contains(DBErr))
            {
                Errs_Solved += MachineErrSplit[i] + Seperator;
            }

            if (!DBErr.Contains(MachineErrSplit[i]))
            {
                Errs_New += MachineErrSplit[i] + Seperator;
            }
        }

        ToReturn[0] = new string[3] { Errs_Solved, Errs_UnSolved, Errs_New };
        ToReturn[1] = MachineErr;
        return ToReturn;

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: What is the expected output??

Comment: By crashed, you mean, it threw an exception? Can you provide some details? And, if `DBErr` contains only "unsolved" errors, shouldn't you have a list of "solved" errors also? Also, storing a list of errors in a single string is a really bad idea.

Comment: No Not an exception but as you said in your comment the Solved and the new error both are identical all i need now is to get the conditions right

Answer (score 1):

```
else //if (MachineErrSplit[i].Contains(DBErr))
{
     Errs_Solved += MachineErrSplit[i] + Seperator;
}

if (!DBErr.Contains(MachineErrSplit[i]))
{
     Errs_New += MachineErrSplit[i] + Seperator;
}
```

These two are identical... assigning the same value to different variables.

Because, else condition of

```
if (DBErr.Contains(MachineErrSplit[i]))
```

is same as

```
if (!DBErr.Contains(MachineErrSplit[i]))
```